# How to safely transfer data from Telegram Mini App to Django+pyTelegramBotAPI without closing the app

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I tried using `WebApp.sendData`, but it closes the app. I guess I should use POST to send data from browser, but I don't know how do I make the backend know the telegram ID of a user whose Mini App sends this POST request.

I don't have any auth except authentication via Telegram. The app is launched via `KeyboardButton`.